# merge 3 or more similar words into one word python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
0         i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1                                        oh this isn’t good
2         account account account has a lot of issues...
3         i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...
4         the sell offs will will will will will continue until moral improves.
```

I have a list of words

```
names = ['is','account','will']
```

in case if the row has 3 or more words from the list I want  to merge them into one word. For example of row has account account account has a lot of issues. I would want my row to look like this account has a lot of issues

```
0         i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1                                        oh this isn’t good
2         account has a lot of issues...
3         i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...
4         the sell offs will continue until moral improves.
```

Comment: `df[~df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(words))]`

Comment: sorry i have posted a wrong question

Comment: Please edit and update the question accordingly.

Comment: yeah i have edited

Comment: Please look at the question, there is no expected output.

Comment: I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but the following code replaces all multiple appending occurences of the word with a single occurrence.

```
for name in ['is', 'account', 'will']:
    yourList = list(re.sub(r"("+name+"\s){2,}", name+" ", txt) for txt in yourList)
```

Used Input:

```
yourList = ["the sell offs will will will will will continue until moral improves.",
            "the sell offs will will will will will is is continue until moral improves.",
            "will will is is is is account account"]
```

Recieved Output:

```
['the sell offs will continue until moral improves.',
 'the sell offs will is continue until moral improves.', 
 'will is account account']
```

Comment: but how would i apply it for each row and my list is way bigger than 3 strings it is just an example

Comment: @yanbiceps should be fixed

Comment: How would i apply this function for the whole column, applying for each row?

Comment: lets say i need to use this function for the column name text

Answer (score 0):

Try this (this should give your desired output. It will return a dataframe):

```
# meta_dict = {
#     r"((account)\s){2,}": "account ",
#     r"((will)\s){2,}": "will ",
#     r"((is)\s){2,}": "is ",
# }

# another way to create the dictionary dynamically based on your input list of names
meta_dict = {}
for name in ["account", "will", "is"]:
    meta_dict.update({r"(("+name+")\s){2,}": f"{name} "})

df_conv = df["col1"].replace(meta_dict, regex=True)

print(df_conv)
```

**Note:** `df` refers to your original dataframe consisting of the sentences in `col1`

Comment: I have more that 3 words it is just an example my list consists of 30 words

Comment: so you add those 30 words accordingly, the answer is just aligned to your example. 
Adding those 30 words won't be a big of a deal, you can iterate and create the `meta_dict` out of it.

Comment: yeah but this data for 1 time I might get different words for the next research and keep changing words would not be efficient

Comment: see this (generating meta_dict is important) and you can generate meta_dict from any source data you would like, you can extract that info in a list and create the dictionary like this: 
`
meta_dict = {}
for name in ["account", "will", "is"]:
    meta_dict.update({r"(("+name+")\s){2,}": f"{name} "})

`

Comment: does {2,} mean that if 2 or more similar words appear?

Comment: correct {2,} denotes the occurrence, and you can modify this value according to your need.

Comment: issue one is that If i have 4 similar words in the the row it returns 2 words when I need only one and it doesn't consider if words have signs between them like is*is>is.is. Appreciate your help

Comment: @yanbiceps {2,0} means two or more occurences not 2 occurences. Even if you have 500 occurences it will still be replaced by a single. Its seems like you didnt even try this or my code? And in which usecase would a . result in a will being taken away?

Comment: I think i will. WIll you? seems reasonable to me

Comment: I am using your code but I still get words that are duplicated one word might be in the beginning the second one in the middle of the sentence and the third one in the end but it doesn't merge them into one

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your dataframe is stored in a variable called **df**

```
# convert dataframe to a list
df_list = df.values.tolist()

for name in names:
    # find and replace duplicate words
    formatted_list = list(re.sub(r"("+ name +"\s){2,}", name +" ", item[0]) for item in df_list)

# convert the formatted list again to a dataframe
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(formatted_list)
df[0] = new_dataframe.replace(df[0], df[0]) 
print(df)
```

so when you print **df**, you'll get

```
                                               0    1           2
0  i only need uxy to hit 20 eod to make up for a...  123  2021-10-15
1                                 oh this isn't good  123  2021-10-15
2     account account account has a lot of issues...  123  2021-10-15
3  i'm tempted to drop my last 800 into some stup...  123  2021-10-15
4  the sell offs will continue until moral improves.  123  2021-10-15
```

try chaging index 0 to the index of the dataset you need. I used 0 here since the text is in the 0th index

Comment: what if I have multiple column before it and i want to apply this function to the column text and keep the other column with date user id as they are

Comment: It gives me TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: please provide a full stacktrace